# Testing that rails model validates date with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm a bit new to Rails and Rspec and as such I'm not sure how to test that date time validations are correct in my model.
I've made a model Event that has start and end times and there's a few imporant conditions on these such as a start time cannot be in the past and the end time must be after the start time.

To ensure these validations I'm using ValidatesTimeliness https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

My model is as follows:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  validates_datetime :start_date,
    :after => :now,
    :after_message => "Event cannot start in the past"

  validates_datetime :end_date,
    :after => :start_date,
    :after_message => "End time cannot be before start time"
end
```

In my RSpec test I have:

```
describe Event do
  let(:event) { FactoryGirl.build :event }
  subject { event }

  context "when start_date is before the current time" do
    it {should_not allow_value(1.day.ago).
        for(:start_date)}
  end

  context "when end_date is before or on start date" do
    it {should_not allow_value(event.start_date - 1.day).
        for(:end_date)}

    it {should_not allow_value(event.start_date).
        for(:end_date)}
  end

  context "when the end_date is after the start_date" do
    it {should allow_value(event.start_date + 1.day).
        for(:end_date)}
  end
end
```

However this doesn't really test that my start date had to be before the exact date time. 
For example if I'd accidentally used `:today` instead of `:now` in my model, these tests would also pass.

I read online that there used to be an RSpec matcher called `validate_date` (http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/1160-validates-timeliness) which would be exactly what I'm looking for but as far as I can tell it's been removed.

My question is how can I improve my tests, do I need to add tests that try the smallest amount of time (i.e. a ms) to ensure the pass/fail accordingly or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `valid?` and `errors.messages`:

- Build an`Event` that passes validation except for your `start_date` and `end_date`
- Set the `start_date` and `end_date` in the **right** order, and assert that `event.valid?` is `true`
- Set the `start_date` and `end_date` in the **wrong** order, and assert that it is not `valid?` and that `event.errors.messages` includes the right validation errors. (Note, you have to call `event.valid?` before checking `event.errors.messages`, otherwise they will be empty)

---

Example for `valid?` and `errors.messages`:

```
 user = User.new
 user.errors.messages #=> {} # no messages, since validations never ran
 user.valid? # => false
 user.errors.messages #=> {:email=>["can't be blank"]}

 user.email = "foo@bar.com"
 user.valid? #=> true
 user.errors.messages #=> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
validates_date :end_time, :after => [:start_time, Proc.new {1.day.from_now_to_date}]
validates_date :start_time, :after => Time.now
```